# Gracefully abort FileStream write loop

Tags: c#, filestream

I have a loop that writes data into a file using FileStream. 
In the middle of operation I want to abort.
If I flush and close it I will have a partial file on the disk. Is there a way to close the FileStream and remove it from the system ? (In Same operation. I know I can just flush close and than delete it myself)

Comment: Well, don't bother flushing.  Yes, simply delete the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*If you need to deal with modifying files...*

May be overkill in your case, but you could use [NTFS transactions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163388.aspx). If you need to abort, just rollback the transaction and the file(s) you modified will return to the state before the transaction start (or disappear completely if it did not exist before the transaction start). This will work even if you don't rollback explicitly (e.g. due to a power cut).

Or you can emulate the transaction by writing to a different file, and then "commit" by replacing the old file with the new.

---

*Otherwise (if you only deal with creating new files, instead of modifying the existing ones)...*

You can just delete the file in your `finally` block, after the stream was closed/disposed (as you already noted).

Comment: I guess that would be it (using the finally block to delete the partial file) I don't want to use NTFS transaction as I don't know which OS and which HD this will run on....  I guess there isn't a "smart way" to do it....